# Git commit issues with multiple files having same name

Tags: git-commit

I am working on a project that contains multiples files with same file name. I am using git to maintain local versions of my changes. After staging the modified files, I notice that files with same name are appearing with status "R" implying replacing one file with another of same name but in different directory tree. How to make sure both are committed without being replaced by one another. I could not find relevant help material regarding this in any of git documentation. 
Since this is a proprietary code, I am pasting only sample directory structure:

```
M  <Proj_Root_Folder>/<dirA>/<dirAA>/file1.h
M  <Proj_Root_Folder>/<dirA>/<dirAA>/file2.h
M  <Proj_Root_Folder>/<dirA>/<dirAA>/file3.h
R  <Proj_Root_Folder>/<dirB>/<dirBA>/file4.h -> <Proj_Root_Folder>/<dirA>/<dirAA>/file4.h
```

Comment: I think I have understood the root cause of the issue now. The changes I made are in 2 ways. One is file content, and another is file name itself. But, I have observed that there are other header files for which both content and file name has been changed. But Git identified and mapped them correctly. As for the status log above, `file4.h` content and its name was changed, but the resulting modified file is present in the same folder only. The question now is what are the possible reasons for improper mapping as it is mapping to file in other directory tree with same filename.

Answer (score 0):

In git "R" means "rename".  Git thinks that ///file4.h is a file that has been moved from where it was originally.  Most likely because the file looks simmer.

Comment: Thanks @Q the Platypus, I was using `git status -s` command earlier and thought that it trying to replace file.  `git status` command log showed it is renaming the file.